# Laravel 4 unable to retrieve value from belongsTo relation using query builder

Tags: laravel-4, query-builder

I have two tables, `organizations` and `categories`. This is how my tables and models are set up:

Tables:

```
organizations
id - integer
category_id - integer, fk
name - string
...

categories
id - integer
name - string
```

Models:

```
class Organization extends Eloquent
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Organization');
    }
}
```

In my routes.php file, I have the following code (where `$category` is equal to "organizations"):

```
$query = Organization::query()
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', $category . '.id')
    ->select('categories.name as category');
$tiles = $query->get();
```

In my view, I am able to perform the following actions without any errors:

```
foreach($tile->comments as $comment)
{
    ...
}
...
$tile->name;
```

However, calling `$tile->category->name` will give me the error `Trying to get property of non-object`. And calling `$tile->category` will just return null. How can I display the category associated with the organization? I am able to retrieve other properties and relations just fine, but this is giving me a problem.

Comment: What is $tile an instance of? Is it an instance of the `Organization` class? If it is, what happens when you do `$tile->category()->name`?

Comment: Calling `$tile->category()->name` gives me the error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`.

I am using Query builder so what is returned is not actually an instance of the Organization class. What is returned when I echo `$tile` or run `print_r($tile)` is an array. But this array does not contain an entry for category.. which is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code: `$category . '.id'` should be `$category . '.category_id'` doing so should make `$tile->category->name` work.

Also please note (*you probably already know this*) that in the code that you provided you are not actually using the belongsTo relation as set in your `Organization` class, you are just using the joined data.

The following would also work using the Eloquent ORM utilizing the models relationship methods:

```
$tiles = Organization::with('category')
->get();

foreach ($tiles as $tile)
{
    echo $tile->name . '<br>';
    echo $tile->category->name . '<br>';
}
```

Or you could do so the other way round from the categories model like so:

```
$tiles = Category::with('organization')
    ->get();

foreach ($tiles as $tile)
{
    echo $tile->name . '<br>';
    foreach($tile->organization as $org)
    {
        echo $org->name . '<br>';
    }
}
```